# Envoy External Authorization with OPA - evaluate fail with large JSON body

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy, open-policy-agent

I have k8s pod running 3 containers: my app, opa, envoy

All my setup follow this guide: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/envoy-authorization/

Everything went well until I have 15kb JSON body.

Checking the OPA container log I see in request.http.body - only about half of JSON there.

```
{
  "decision_id": "",
  "error": {},
  "input": {
    "attributes": {
      "destination": {
        "address": {
          "Address": {
            "SocketAddress": {
              "PortSpecifier": {
                "PortValue": 8000
              },
              "address": "10.244.8.102"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "request": {
        "http": {
          "body": "only half of JSON body come here",
          "headers": {
            ":authority": "api-service.com",
            ":method": "PUT",
            ":path": "/api",
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-length": "14822",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "x-envoy-decorator-operation": "....",
            "x-envoy-internal": "true",
            "x-forwarded-for": "10.244.6.0",
            "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
            "x-istio-attributes": "..."  
          },
          "host": "....com",
          "id": "12114967460600931537",
          "method": "PUT",
          "path": "/api",
          "size": 14822
        }
      },
      "source": {
        "address": {
          "Address": {
            "SocketAddress": {
              "PortSpecifier": {
                "PortValue": 34670
              },
              "address": "10.244.3.164"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "parsed_path": [
      "api"
    ],
    "parsed_query": {}
  },
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "Decision Log",
  "query": "data.app.allow",
  "type": "openpolicyagent.org/decision_logs"
}
```

I tried increase with_request_body.

```
http_filters:
   - name: envoy.ext_authz
        config:
          with_request_body:
            max_request_bytes: 819200
            allow_partial_message: true
            failure_mode_allow: false
```

Is there any other thing I missed?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally make it works by increasing max_request_bytes.

```
name: envoy.ext_authz
        config:
          with_request_body:
            max_request_bytes: 819200
```

I configured this before in configmap but forgot to restart the pod. Just redeploy everything with new max_request_bytes - it's ok now

Reference: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/buffer/v3/buffer.proto.html?highlight=max_request_bytes
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors in the Envoy logs ?

What is the data that you are trying to send ? Does it need to be part of OPA's *input* document or can you leverage OPA's [bundle](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/external-data/#option-3-bundle-api) feature.

Comment: Hi Ash Narkar, there is no Envoy Log for this error, I have a REST API /api (PUT) accept JSON BODY. Envoy is configured to take care of authorizing this API. So the input is composed by envoy as part of OPA's input, then send to OPA engine. please refer to this https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/envoy-authorization/

Comment: This seems to be a limitation with the Envoy ext authz plugin. Is there a limit to the amount of bytes sent in the ext authz payload ?

Comment: Also is Envoy buffering the data ?